# Prove $f$ has at least one zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=D(a,r)$.
Suppose that $f$ is analytic on a domain containing  $\overline D$.
If $|f(z)|>m$ for all $|z-a|=r$ and $|f(z_0)|<m$ for some $z_0\in D$,
I'm trying to prove that $f$ has at least one zero in $D$.

I tried:

Suppose $f$ contains no zero in $D$, thus, $\frac{1}{f}$ is analytic on $D$.
Consider $\frac{1}{f},$ for this function, we have $|\frac{1}{f}(z)|\leq m$ for all $|z-a|=r$ and $|\frac{1}{f}(z_0)|\geq m$ for some $z_0\in D.$ Hence, $\max_{\bar{D}}|\frac{1}{f}(z)|\neq\max_{\partial D}\frac{1}{f}(z),$ therefore, $\frac{1}{f}$ is not analytic on $D$ or not continuous on $\bar{D}.$ Therefore, there is a contradiction. Hence, $f$ has at least one zero in $D.$

Comment: I assume $D\subseteq \mathbb C$?

Comment: Yes, $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @5xum If $f$ has no zeroes in $D$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is analytic. But we want to get a contradiction, so $\frac{1}{f}$ shouldn't be analytic, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $f$ has no zeroes in $D$, then $\frac1f$ is analytic on $D$ and continuous on $\overline D$

Comment: But I don't get why $\frac{1}{f}$ is not analytic on $D$ and continuous on $\bar{D}$?

Comment: @Kelan I just re-read your question. What do you mean "$\frac1f$ is **not** analytic on $D$"?

Comment: You can obtain new inequalities on $\frac{1}{f}$, and now you can obtain a contradiction.

Comment: So, by maximum principle, the maximum of $\frac{1}{f}$ in the boundary is not equal to the maximum of it in the closure, so $\frac{1}{f}$ is not analytic or not continuous on $\bar{D}$, right?

Comment: @Kelan What you wrote down makes no sense to me. Try to edit your original post with a solid rigorous proof, and I can comment on it. What you wrote down so far looks like you **may** have the right idea, but I don't know yet.

Comment: @5xum I did it right now.

Comment: @Kelan Looks good! I would just add, when you write " therefore, $\frac1f$ is not analytic on $D$ ", that this is because of the maximum principle (I understand that's what you used, but some casual reader might not).

Comment: @5xum Cool! Thanks for your patience!